# Producing a geometric sequence using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to produce a geometric sequence, something similar to 1, 2, 4, 8...

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

lower_price = 1
upper_price = 2
total_grids = 10

grid_box = np.linspace(lower_price , upper_price, total_grids, retstep=True)

print(grid_box)
```

This outputs:

```
(array([1.        , 1.11111111, 1.22222222, 1.33333333, 1.44444444,
       1.55555556, 1.66666667, 1.77777778, 1.88888889, 2.        ]), 0.1111111111111111)
```

This code creates an arithmetic, rather than a geometric sequence. How can I fix this code to produce the latter as opposed to the former?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html), not `np.linspace`:

For example,

```py
# Lower bound is 2**0 == 1
# Upper bound is 2**10 == 1024
np.logspace(0, 10, 10, base=2)
```

outputs:

```py
[1.00000000e+00 2.16011948e+00 4.66611616e+00 1.00793684e+01
 2.17726400e+01 4.70315038e+01 1.01593667e+02 2.19454460e+02
 4.74047853e+02 1.02400000e+03]
```

---

If you're trying to get 10 values between 1 and 2, use:

```py
# Lower bound is 2**0 == 1
# Upper bound is 2**1 == 2
np.logspace(0, 1, 10, base=2)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for editing my question. I am sorry if I asked in an unclear way. This code does what I want. But how can I change values like between 5 and 20? I'm confused why "0, 1" instead of "1, 2"?

Comment: Your question was pretty clear, but I just wanted to touch up the wording a little bit. It'd depend on what base you wanted to use. You'd want to use `log_<whatever base you wanted to use>(lower_bound)` for the first argument, with something similar for the upper bound (except using the value of the upper rather than lower bound). I would strongly recommend looking at the docs for `np.logspace`, since the arguments aren't the most intuitive IMO.

Comment: Also take a look at [`geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html).

Answer (score 1):

'percentage' gives the % increment between each values. You can see that it remains constant for constant total_grids and changes only if you change it.

```
import numpy as np

lower_price = 10
upper_price = 2000
total_grids = 10

grid_box = np.linspace(lower_price , upper_price, total_grids, retstep=True)

full_range = upper_price - lower_price
correctedStartValue = grid_box[0][1] - lower_price
percentage = (correctedStartValue * 100) / full_range 

print(grid_box)
print(percentage)
```

Comment: What I mean is... when you check the percentage difference between these numbers it is not fixed because it's a step size, and it's not what I intend to do.

I'm trying to have a fixed percentage like 1% above the previous number, and then again 1% above the previous number like that... so it's like 1, 2, 4, 8

Check the difference between this: ['1.050', '1.103', '1.158', '1.216', '1.276', '1.340', '1.407', '1.477', '1.551', '1.629'] - it's 5% each time from previous number.